# Searching an ArrayList of objects

Tags: java, search, arraylist

For my current project I have to search through an ArrayList of ZipCode objects in order to find the furthest ZipCode from the int zip entered by the user.

Here's the directions for writing the method that I'm having trouble with:
public ZipCode findFurthest(int pZip) - find the ZipCode that is furthest from the provided zip code. Return null if the zip code is not found. For example, the furthest from zip code 75234 is ADAK, AK 99546.

Within my code I'm using the public int distance(int zip1, int zip2) method to calculate the distance between the user entered zip and the zip of the ArrayList object. I'm not sure how to write the correct if statement in order to find the ZipCode that's the furthest away.
Thank you for the help, I greatly appreciate it.

```
public class ZipCodeDatabase {

    private ArrayList<ZipCode> list;

    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class ZipCodeDatabase
     */
    public ZipCodeDatabase()
    {
        // initialise instance variables
        list = new ArrayList<ZipCode>();
    }

    /**
     * Method findZip searches loops through the ArrayList and returns all of the ZipCodes
     * 
     * @param  int zip
     * @return     null
     */
    public ZipCode findZip(int zip)
    {
        // put your code here

        for(ZipCode z : list){
            if(z.getZip() == zip){
                return z;   
            }

        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Method distance calculates the distance between two user entered zip codes numbers
     * 
     * @param  int zip1, int zip2
     * @return int
     */
    public int distance(int zip1, int zip2){   

        ZipCode z1 = new ZipCode(zip1);
        ZipCode z2 = new ZipCode(zip2);
        z1 = findZip(zip1);
        z2 = findZip(zip2);

        double lat1 = z1.getLat();
        double lat2 = z2.getLat();
        double lon1 = z1.getLon();
        double lon2 = z2.getLon();
        final int EARTH_RADIUS = 3959;
        if(list.contains(z1) && list.contains(z2)){
            double p1= Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat1)) * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lon1))
                * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat2)) * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lon2));

            double p2 = Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat1)) * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(lon1))
                * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat2)) * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(lon2));

            double p3 = Math.sin(Math.toRadians(lat1)) * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(lat2));

            double distance = Math.acos(p1 + p2 + p3) * EARTH_RADIUS;

            double d = distance;

            int dist = (int) d;

            return dist;
        }
        else{
            return -1; 
        }

    }

    /**
     * Method withinRadius finds all of the ZipCode objects within the radius of the entered 
     * zip
     * @param  int pZip, int pRadius
     * @return list
     */
    public ArrayList<ZipCode> whithinRadius(int pZip, int pRadius){

        for(ZipCode z: list){
            if(distance(pZip, z.getZip()) <= pRadius){
                ArrayList<ZipCode> radius = new ArrayList<>();
                radius.add(z);
                return radius;
            }
            else{
                ArrayList<ZipCode> radius = new ArrayList<>();
            }
        }   
        return list;
    }

    /**
     * Method findFurthest finds the furthest ZipCode from the user entered zip
     * 
     * @param  int pZip
     * @return null
     */
    public ZipCode findFurthest(int pZip){

        if(list.contains(pZip)){

            for(ZipCode z : list){
                if(distance(pZip, z.getZip()) < distance(pZip, z.getZip())){
                    return z;
                }

            }

        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Method search find all of the ZipCode objects with a city name that contains the user 
     * entered string
     * @param  String str
     * @return list
     */
    public ArrayList<ZipCode> search(String str){
        ArrayList<ZipCode> matchStr = new ArrayList<>();
        for(ZipCode z : list){
            if(z.getCity().contains(str)){

                matchStr.add(z);
                return matchStr;
            }
            else{

                return matchStr;
            }

        }
        return list;
    }

    /**
     * Method readZipCodeDatabase reads the file containing all of the zip codes
     * 
     * @param  String filename
     * @return int
     */
    public void readZipCodeData(String filename){

        Scanner inFS = null;
        FileInputStream fileByteStream = null;
        try{
            //open the file and set delimeters
            fileByteStream = new FileInputStream(filename);
            inFS = new Scanner(fileByteStream);
            inFS.useDelimiter("[,\r\n]+");
            filename = "zipcodes.txt";
            // continue while there is more data to read
            while(inFS.hasNext()) {

                // read five data elements
                int zip = inFS.nextInt();
                String city = inFS.next();
                String state = inFS.next();
                double lat = inFS.nextDouble();
                double lon = inFS.nextDouble();
                ZipCode z = new ZipCode(zip, city, state, lat, lon);
                ArrayList<ZipCode> list = new ArrayList<>(); 
                list.add(z);
            }
            fileByteStream.close();
            //error while reading the file
        }catch(IOException error1){
            System.out.println("Error: Unable to read file: " + filename);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your findFurthest method is comparing the same calculated distance on each side of the expression if(distance(pZip, z.getZip()) < distance(pZip, z.getZip())).

Answer (score 0):

This snippet should do the trick:

```
public ZipCode findFurthest(int pZip)
{
    return list.stream()
        .max((zip0, zip1) -> distance(pZip, zip0.getZip())
            - distance(pZip, zip1.getZip()))
        .orElse(null);
}
```

It's nothing fancy - just a regular min-max code. Please, write tests to check if this method really works.